# HTML ignoring <input type="date"> default value

Tags: html, forms

`<input type="date">` shows me `2024-01-06` (today) although `value` is set to `2024-01-04`. I checked if I have the right date format but it seems so.
I have assured myself that `$res["date"]` has really value of `2024-01-04`.

Could you please help?

#### My code:

```
<input type="date" name="date" id="date"
    style="display: inline; margin-left: 15px;" 
    <?php echo ($res["date"]) ? "value=\"$res[date]\"" : "" ?>>
```

#### Browser:

I am using Firefox 121.0

Code:

`<input type="date" name="date" id="date" style="display: inline; margin-left: 15px;" value="2024-01-04">`

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: `<input type="number">` is a typo? Can you please _not_ post [images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)?

Comment: I cannot [reproduce your problem](https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/poYyrjd).

Comment: Cannot reproduce either, and I also get KIKO's format: `01/04/2024`

Comment: No, I don't set anything.